# oracle database - sql for counting the columns with the same id with the one in current row

Tags: oracle, count

I have an oracle database and a few tables and with this query:

```
select rap.DENUMIRE,a3.ID,op.FK_ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANEXA3_TABEL1_ROWS) AS count
from ANEXA3_TABEL1_ROWS a3
inner join RAPORTORI_AMB rap on rap.id = ch.FK_ID_RAPORTOR
inner join ANEXA3_TABEL1_OP op on op.FK_ID = a3.ID
```

the result is:

```
DENUMIRE    ID  FK_ID   COUNT
SC AAA      720 720     7
SC AAA      720 720     7
SC AAA      720 720     7
SC AAA      741 741     7
SC AAA      720 720     7
SC AAA      720 720     7
SC AAA      742 742     7
```

and I'd want to select in COUNT the number of columns with FK_ID equals to the ID in the current row. In this example, I'd want the following result:

```
DENUMIRE    ID  FK_ID   COUNT
SC AAA      720 720     5
SC AAA      720 720     5
SC AAA      720 720     5
SC AAA      741 741     1
SC AAA      720 720     5
SC AAA      720 720     5
SC AAA      742 742     1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you distinguish between the five records SS AAA 720 720 5? Where's your Primary Key?

Comment: It was just a select from other tables - everyone with his PK of course, but irrelevant info. @Dmitry answered my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select rap.DENUMIRE,a3.ID, op.FK_ID, count(*) over (partition by op.FK_ID) AS count
  from ANEXA3_TABEL1_ROWS a3
 inner join RAPORTORI_AMB rap on rap.id = ch.FK_ID_RAPORTOR
 inner join ANEXA3_TABEL1_OP op on op.FK_ID = a3.ID
```

Comment: with that info, do you know how I can find out if it's the first occurence of that id-match ?

Comment: I think, you need to read about analytic functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 For first occurence, you need `row_number` function: `row_number() over (partition by op.FK_ID order by op.FK_ID)`. For first occurence function gives 1, for second - 2, and so on.